# Tumblr API How do I access the individual values from the following array in php

Tags: php, api, multidimensional-array, tumblr

I'm using the tumblr API and the following code:

```
$var = xhttp::toQueryArray($response['body']);
print_r($var);
```

This print on the screen the following:

```
Array ( [{"meta":{"status":200,"msg":"OK"},"response":{"user":{"name":"lukebream","likes":0,"following":8,"default_post_format":"html","blogs":[{"name":"lukebream","url":"http:\/\/lukebream.tumblr.com\/","followers":5,"primary":true,"title":"Untitled","admin":true,"queue":0,"ask":false,"tweet":"N"}]}}}] => )
```

How can I access the individual elements and assign them to variables?

Here is what I have finished with:

```
$tumblr->set_token($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
$data = array();
$data['post'] = array();        
$response = $tumblr->fetch('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info', $data);    

if($response['successful']) {
    echo $response['json']['response']['url'];
} else {
    echo "api call failed. {$response[body]}<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), you can parse it using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**Usage Example :**

```
//I used file_get_contents() to keep things simple
$jsonData = file_get_contents("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/lukebream.tumblr.com/info?api_key=<api_key_here>");
```

The $jsonData contains :

```
{
    "meta":{
        "status":200,
        "msg":"OK"
        },
    "response":{
        "blog":{
            "title":"Untitled",
            "posts":61,
            "name":"lukebream",
            "url":"http:\/\/lukebream.tumblr.com\/",
            "updated":1321830278,
            "description":"",
            "ask":false,
            "likes":0
            }
        }
}
```

after it goes through `json_decode()`, we get a PHP object, so :

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonData);
```

will return :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => 200
            [msg] => OK
        )
    [response] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Untitled
                    [posts] => 61
                    [name] => lukebream
                    [url] => http://lukebream.tumblr.com/
                    [updated] => 1321830278
                    [description] => 
                    [ask] => 
                    [likes] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

Then you can access the data like with any other object.

Comment: I know its JSON but  I cannot get anything to work correctly using json_decode() Can You give me an example please

Comment: thanks for your help I got it sorted eventually ! thanks again

Comment: @LukeBream If my solution didn't help you, post the code you used as a solution to your problem (for future visitor with the same issue) then mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use json_decode($str, TRUE): this will return an ARRAY instead of an object, much easier to play with!